# Why is this script sending blank emails without using template in SugarCRM?

Tags: php, email, sugarcrm

This is my code to send emails in SugarCRM CE 6.5.x version,

```
<?php 
if (!defined('sugarEntry') || !sugarEntry) die('Not A Valid EntryPoint');


require_once('include/SugarPHPMailer.php');
$msg = new SugarPHPMailer();

$emailObj = new Email();
$defaults = $emailObj->getSystemDefaultEmail(); 

//Setup template
require_once('XTemplate/xtpl.php');
$xtpl = new XTemplate('custom/modules/Users/ChangePassword.html');

//assign recipients email and name
$rcpt_email = 'sohan.tirpude@mphasis.com';
$rcpt_name = 'Sohan';

//Set RECIPIENT's address
$email = $msg->AddAddress($rcpt_email, $rcpt_name);

//Send msg to users
$template_name = 'User';

//Assign values to variables in template
$xtpl->assign('EMAIL_NAME', $rcpt_name);
$xtpl->parse();
//$body = "Hello Sohan, It's been 80 days that you haven't changed your password. Please take some time out to change password first before it expires.";
$msg->From = $defaults['email'];
$msg->FromName = $defaults['name']; 
$msg->Body = from_html(trim($xtpl->text($template_name))); 
//$msg->Body = $body;
$msg->Subject = 'Change Password Request';
$msg->prepForOutbound();
$msg->AddAddress($email); 
$msg->setMailerForSystem();

//Send the message, log if error occurs
if (!$msg->Send()){
    $GLOBALS['log']->fatal('Error sending e-mail: ' . $msg->ErrorInfo);
}

?>
```

Now this script send blanks emails, and when I hardcoded body part then it is takes those message written in body, and sends an email. So, please help me here.

Comment: What does from_html(trim($xtpl->text($template_name))); return?

Comment: Well, it's not showing any error or any message

Comment: Question is, does it return any content? If the email sends with a hardcoded body but not with that, then the first thing I would look at is am I sending it an empty body?

Comment: Yeah but I have content in my template...

Comment: But we know there's a problem in there somewhere - if you check the contents of your variables at different points it will give a clue as to where.

Comment: Hello, when I print "from_html(trim($xtpl->text($template_name)))"...I got blank page but when I print only $xtpl then I got my template text inside it. So, why it's not working here?

Comment: Looks like it's most likely a problem with your templating - try printing $xtpl->text($template_name) - I suspect that's not doing what you expect it to.